# Getting the 10 most recent reviews for each location

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am Writing a Query, using pools in Node and Express. What I am attempting to do it, get the 10 most recent reviews for each location. I am attempting to do this using the following code.

```
var returnObj = [];

router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    const LocationsQuery = 'SELECT locationID FROM locations GROUP BY locationID';

    connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
            if (err) {                  
                connection.rollback(function() {
                    connection.release();
                });
            } else {
                connection.query(LocationsQuery, function(err, results) {
                    if (err) {      
                        connection.rollback(function() {
                            connection.release();
                        });
                    }   

                    for(var i = 0; i < results.length;i++){
                        var dataQuery = `SELECT  locations.businessName, locations.address, locations.city, locations.state, locations.zipCode, locations.Country, r.comfort,
                                            r.timeliness, r.politeness, r.accessibility, r.averageRating, r.food, r.breakRoom, r.restroom
                                            FROM (SELECT reviews.locationID, reviews.comfort,  reviews.timeliness, reviews.politeness,  reviews.accessibility,
                                                    (reviews.comfort +  reviews.timeliness + reviews.politeness +  reviews.accessibility) / 4 AS averageRating, 
                                                    reviews.food, reviews.breakRoom, reviews.restroom
                                                    FROM reviews 
                                                    WHERE reviews.locationID = ${results[i].locationID}) r 
                                        LEFT JOIN locations on locations.locationID = r.locationID   
                                        LIMIT ${config.limit}`

                        connection.query(dataQuery,function(err, res) {

                            if (err) {      
                                connection.rollback(function() {
                                    connection.release();
                                });
                            } 

                            //Get the Averages of the ratings then creates 
                            // Json Object out of the MYSQL return Data 
                            object = setup(res)
                            returnObj.append(object)
                            console.log(object)
                        });
                    } //End For loop
                });
            }    
        });
    });
    res.send(returnObj);
});
```

The issue I am running into is this doing n+1 queries to the database. (The one to get all the locations, and n to loop through those and get 10)

In theory this code does do exactly what I want as it does "get" the 10 most recent reviews for each location. The issue I am running into is the fact that I cannot just `res.send()` due to it sending before every query is complete. I have tried to append to the `returnObj` and then send that, like above, but that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get the data in either a single query or how I can make this wait until all of the locations most recent reviews are queried?

Comment: Create promises for each query and use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them.

Comment: Or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group for how to do a single query that gets N results per group, instead of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database opration is async in nodejs so you need to handle async behaviour and you can not call mysql query inside for loop. so here is your final solution

```
    import { resolve } from "path";
import { rejects } from "assert";

var returnObj = [];

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const LocationsQuery = 'SELECT locationID FROM locations GROUP BY locationID';

    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                connection.rollback(function () {
                    connection.release();
                });
            } else {
                connection.query(LocationsQuery, function (err, results) {
                    if (err) {
                        connection.rollback(function () {
                            connection.release();
                        });
                    }
                    var promises = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        promises.push(performopration, results[i], config);
                    } //End For loop

                    Promise.all(promises)
                    .then(() => {
                        res.send(returnObj);
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

function performopration(connection, results, config) {
    var dataQuery = `SELECT  locations.businessName, locations.address, locations.city, locations.state, locations.zipCode, locations.Country, r.comfort,
                                            r.timeliness, r.politeness, r.accessibility, r.averageRating, r.food, r.breakRoom, r.restroom
                                            FROM (SELECT reviews.locationID, reviews.comfort,  reviews.timeliness, reviews.politeness,  reviews.accessibility,
                                                    (reviews.comfort +  reviews.timeliness + reviews.politeness +  reviews.accessibility) / 4 AS averageRating, 
                                                    reviews.food, reviews.breakRoom, reviews.restroom
                                                    FROM reviews 
                                                    WHERE reviews.locationID = ${results.locationID}) r 
                                        LEFT JOIN locations on locations.locationID = r.locationID   
                                        LIMIT ${config.limit}`;

    return new Promise((resolve, rejects) => {
        connection.query(dataQuery, function (err, res) {

            if (err) {
                connection.rollback(function () {
                    connection.release();
                });
                rejects();
            }

            //Get the Averages of the ratings then creates 
            // Json Object out of the MYSQL return Data 
            object = setup(res)
            returnObj.append(object);
            console.log(object);
            resolve();
        })
    })


}
```